# MySQL Trigger for after insert and update table

Tags: mysql, triggers

i was created a table for content management.I am not familiar with Mysql trigger.

```
     Key    Default     
      a     varchar(50)      
      b     varchar(50)      
      c     text      
      status    varchar(100)
```

This my table.I was created a trigger When each table  update table  change the status.

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER tr2 BEFORE insert or UPDATE ON p
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     SET NEW.status = '1';
    END;
   $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger only update when the row will be modified .How can create trigger for  change the "status" during every insert and update.. Please help me any one

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct syntax. Just create a trigger before update

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER tr2 BEFORE UPDATE ON p
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     SET NEW.date = '1';
    END;
   $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

and make the default value for column `status = '1'`.

```
CREATE TABLE p(
a varchar(50),
b varchar(50),
c text,
status varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
);
```

That way whenever you insert a row into p and don't specify a value for status, status will be `1`. You could create another trigger `BEFORE INSERT` but I don't recommend that. And the above solution does the same.